# Why assigning a regular pointer to a pointer-to-const is allowed but not the opposite?

Tags: c, pointers

Assigning a regular pointer *ptr2* to a pointer-to-const *ptr1* like shown in the code below does not produce any warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    const int *ptr1 = &a;
    int *ptr2 = &b;
    ptr1 = ptr2;
    return 0;
}
```

However, assigning the pointer-to-const *ptr1* to the regular pointer *ptr2* produces a warning during compilation, and according to the book I am following (C Primer Plus by Stephen Patra), can lead to undefined behaviour.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    const int *ptr1 = &a;
    int *ptr2 = &b;
    ptr2 = ptr1;
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, when one pointer is assigned to another, it is equivalent to making the two pointers point at the same object. So if I were to write a diagram, both cases should look like this.
[image]
According to my diagram, the order of assignment won't change the outcome. Whether I assign ptr1 to ptr2 or ptr2 to ptr1 should give me the same diagram, but now I am not sure whether my understanding is correct. Can anyone explain the reason why the two cases are different, and tell me whether the diagram I drew is correct or not please.

Comment: FWIW, when I try to compile your second example I get an error: `invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @Dai :  Likely you used C++ rather then C compilation. In C++ it is an error requiring a case (preferably a `const_cast`).

Comment: @Dai :  Likely you used C++ rather then C compilation. In C++ it is an error requiring a cast (preferably a `const_cast`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram applies only to the first example.  In the second both pointers refer to `a` rather then 'b'.  But that is not the problem.

The semantics of the `const` qualifier on `ptr1` are that the data referenced cannot be changed *through that pointer*. It does not mean that the data itself is constant, it is the pointer that is qualified, and imposes no specific constraint on the data except as accessed through such a pointer.

So:

```
ptr1 = ptr2;
```

does not generate a warning as it assigns a less restrictive type to a more restrictive type, so is "safe" in that it allows no greater access that already allowed through `ptr2`.

On the other hand:

```
ptr2 = ptr1;
```

Is valid but semantically questionable - in the sense that it is not normally desirable to relax a restriction imposed by `ptr1` - and likely to be unintentional.  Hence the warning.

Where the assignment is deliberate, an explicit cast should be used to indicate it as such and to suppress the warning.  But generally it is indicative of poor design or a semantic error, and you should consider that before arbitrarily casting it away.  Casting away of a `const` should only be necessary when interfacing to third-party code that lacks appropriate "const-safety".

Answer (score 0):

```
const int *ptr1 = &a;
int *ptr2 = &b;
```

This essentially says that any access through `ptr1` will be read only. C will not allow you to write to the pointed to memory. And access through `ptr2` *can* be read/write.

So `ptr1 = ptr2` is valid as the memory pointed to by `ptr2` is read/write. The fact that `ptr1` will never write to it does not violate any assumptions.

`ptr2 = ptr` on the other hand is illegal as through `ptr2` the memory could be written to, but that memory was defines as being read only. So that violates the restrictions put into place by the programmer. If if these restrictions are violated no-one knows what will happen.

You can force it with a cast: `ptr2 = (int*)ptr1`. But in that case you have to be sure *no writes* are being done throug `ptr2`.

If you need this, this is a sign your API is badly designed and you should change that. Some C standard functions suffer from this, but that is because they where designed before `const` was introduced to C. Do not follow their example.

Comment: Re “C will not allow you to write to the pointed to memory”: The C standard does not require C implementations to enforce this, just as the C standard does not require C implementations to disallow accessing arrays out of bounds.

Comment: As `ptr1` is a `const int*` the C std requires that `*ptr1 = 5` is illegal. You cannot write to a memory location through a const pointer (which is what I meant to say). You _can_ write to that same location through a non const pointer though so `*(int*)ptr1 = 5` _is_ allowed, but undefined behaviour if the memory happens to be effectively read only.

Comment: Re “which is what I meant to say”: Teaching has to be done through the words that are actually written, not through the words that are meant. Students cannot read minds.